# When $z+2yx+x^2$ is a perfect square?

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

I got two big integers $z$ and $y$ where $gcd(z,y) = 1$
$$z+2yx+x^2$$

How to find when f(x) = $z+2yx+x^2$ is a perfect squere for positive integer $x$?

Is this problem is as hard as [Integer factorization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)? If it is, how can it be transformed into the form of:

$$a^2 = b^2 mod(c)$$

So optimizations like [Dixon's factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method) could be applied

Comment: Think $(y+x)^2$, expand and compare

Comment: @imranfat yeah but you know nothing about $z$ and $y$, so I am not sure how it can be useful.

Comment: Then I think I did not understand the whole problem correctly. I thought you pick $z=y^2$ to get a perfect square trinomial. There is evidently more to it...